# Does solr support overlapping range facets?

Tags: solr

I have not found any example for overlapping range based facets
Do solr even support overlapping range facets? example, something like : [0-10],[5-15],[10-20]

Comment: If you want to explicitly define limits, using `facet.query` is probably the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

Well a facet is a filter, so if you add multiple, separate range filters you're essentially saying "filter for values 0-10 **and** filter for values 5-15". So only the values in range 5-10 satisfy both those filters and that's all you'll get. If you want results that satisfy *any* of the ranges, you could join them into a single facet query parameter with an OR operator, e.g.

```
    fq = count:[0 TO 10] OR count[5 TO 15]
```

and that's the same as filtering `count:[0 TO 15]`. Just depends what kind of functionality you expect from overlapping ranges.